# How can I make BizTalk read files in a directory in a certain order?

Tags: biztalk, messaging

I'm not a BizTalk expert but my colleagues that are, say that BizTalk cannot read files from a folder in a ordered way. Only socket and queues support this.

They asked me to write a small tool that will read the files ordered by filename or by creation date and put those on a queue.

But isn't there a way that this can be done in BizTalk itself? Personally I'm not fond of the idea that a custom windows service has to be made to accomplish this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't I'm afraid. File transport cannot guarantee order. You need to use an adapter which supports ordered delivery like MSMQ, SQL, or WCF.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to put the code that I have to write for my windows service in BizTalk itself?

Comment: The only things I can think of: 1) It may be possible to write or find a custom adapter which does this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559841(v=bts.20).aspx. 2) You could embed the ordering detail in the message content itself which would allow you to implement ordered delivery by using the order indicated in the messages.

Comment: @Jochen did you figure this out?  I found code for a modified FileAdapter, it doesn't order the files it does some other stuff but it could be modified to order them before they're submitted, let me know I could put it up on bitbucket.

Comment: @Derik it was decided that making the windows service will be quicker than getting it done in BizTalk.

Answer (score 3):

Look in the sdk, there is an example of a file adapter.  In the past I've modified that code to read the files in a specific order.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578623(v=bts.10).aspx

I don't have the code handy but found [this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_j4r3s5Wo7u8/S34kw8zDXDI/AAAAAAAABrE/J8PdqcFCUgk/s1600-h/BTA_4.JPG).  From [here](http://pamelayang.blogspot.com/2010/02/custom-biztalk-file-adapter-biztalk.html).  It gives you an idea as to where you can order the files by date or name.